# React+Redux: How to add dropdownfield dynamically

Tags: reactjs, redux

My task says when users select children count other than 0 (which is a dropdown), then we have to check the boolean condition first based on which display the option to select ages for no of children selected.
i.e if children count is 3, and RequestAge boolean is true, then I have to show 3 dropdowns below with age count from 0 to 12. So I called a function on "OnChange" event as below but even 1 dropdown is also not displaying
And also default value of the dropdown is 'Select Age'. Can you help me.

```
if (RequestAge)
{
    if (childrenCount > 0)
    {
        var AgeOptions = ['Select Age', '1','2','3'....'12'];
        return (
                <label>Enter Age of Children'</label>
                <select name='selectAge' id='selectAge'>
                    <option key='Select Age' value='Select Age'>this.props.AgeOptions}                
</option>
                        </select>
                )
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should post the actual code (and more of it.. like the whole component). It's hard to tell from this pseudo-code where the actual problems are.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below mentioned code

```
render:function()
  {
     var AgeOptions = ['1','2','3'];

    return(
      <div>
      Select Age:
       <select>
       <option value="0" selected>Select Age</option>
        {AgeOptions.map(function(age){
          return(
             <option value={age} >{age}</option>
            )
        })}
       </select>
      </div>

      )
  }
```

Working Sample [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/27934/)

Comment: Thanks Dhaval for your response. Would it work on the dropdown OnChange event.And does createclass work on Redux framework, how to refer the Combobox in the page. Sorry for many questions.

Comment: @ChakravartyA: you don't need to implement a createClass you can directly used the render method code  {AgeOptions.map(function(age){
          return(
             <option value={age} >{age}</option>
            )
        })} in your code

Comment: OK thanks, got it. Now how to add more select based on dynamic count. As I mentioned above, if count is 2, then 2 dropdowns and if 3 then 3 dropdowns.

Comment: @ChakravartyA:I have updated my Demo link over there you will find your answer don't forgot to upvote and accept answer :)